# How to find in multidimensional array values that are the same and make a new array with only unique value?

Tags: php, arrays, function, sorting, multidimensional-array

I have an array that has stored results from my MySQL database.

```
$time = "14:51:00"

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => richard
            [id] => 61
            [chauffeurId] => 60
            [lat] => 53.0291365
            [lon] => 5.65739468598697
            [pickupdate] => 2021-01-25
            [departuretime] => 12:55:00
            [arrivalTime] => 13:46:00
            [finalDestination] => 5.81155877224893,52.9808856
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => Jan
            [id] => 64
            [chauffeurId] => 63
            [lat] => 53.19968475
            [lon] => 5.80069089560234
            [pickupdate] => 2021-01-25
            [departuretime] => 12:45:00
            [arrivalTime] => 13:51:00
            [finalDestination] => 5.81155877224893,52.9808856
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [name] => richard
            [id] => 61
            [chauffeurId] => 60
            [lat] => 53.0291365
            [lon] => 5.65739468598697
            [pickupdate] => 2021-01-25
            [departuretime] => 13:49:00
            [arrivalTime] => 14:50:00
            [finalDestination] => 5.81155877224893,52.9808856
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [name] => joris
            [id] => 59
            [chauffeurId] => 58
            [lat] => 52.9026474
            [lon] => 5.59003021194087
            [pickupdate] => 
            [departuretime] => 
            [arrivalTime] => 
            [finalDestination] => 
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [name] => frans
            [id] => 60
            [chauffeurId] => 59
            [lat] => 53.018652
            [lon] => 5.533441
            [pickupdate] => 
            [departuretime] => 
            [arrivalTime] => 
            [finalDestination] => 
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [name] => henk
            [id] => 62
            [chauffeurId] => 61
            [lat] => 53.02030965
            [lon] => 5.53122986346911
            [pickupdate] => 
            [departuretime] => 
            [arrivalTime] => 
            [finalDestination] => 
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [name] => Joop
            [id] => 65
            [chauffeurId] => 64
            [lat] => 52.9026474
            [lon] => 5.59003021194087
            [pickupdate] => 
            [departuretime] => 
            [arrivalTime] => 
            [finalDestination] => 
        )

)
```

I have in this array two array's which have equal ['chauffeurId'].
So I only want one of the two. The one that I want, needs to have the  ['arrivaltime'] that is the closest to the time stored in the $time variable.

The array then needs to look like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => Jan
            [id] => 64
            [chauffeurId] => 63
            [lat] => 53.19968475
            [lon] => 5.80069089560234
            [pickupdate] => 2021-01-25
            [departuretime] => 12:45:00
            [arrivalTime] => 13:51:00
            [finalDestination] => 5.81155877224893,52.9808856
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => richard
            [id] => 61
            [chauffeurId] => 60
            [lat] => 53.0291365
            [lon] => 5.65739468598697
            [pickupdate] => 2021-01-25
            [departuretime] => 13:49:00
            [arrivalTime] => 14:50:00
            [finalDestination] => 5.81155877224893,52.9808856
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [name] => joris
            [id] => 59
            [chauffeurId] => 58
            [lat] => 52.9026474
            [lon] => 5.59003021194087
            [pickupdate] => 
            [departuretime] => 
            [arrivalTime] => 
            [finalDestination] => 
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [name] => frans
            [id] => 60
            [chauffeurId] => 59
            [lat] => 53.018652
            [lon] => 5.533441
            [pickupdate] => 
            [departuretime] => 
            [arrivalTime] => 
            [finalDestination] => 
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [name] => henk
            [id] => 62
            [chauffeurId] => 61
            [lat] => 53.02030965
            [lon] => 5.53122986346911
            [pickupdate] => 
            [departuretime] => 
            [arrivalTime] => 
            [finalDestination] => 
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [name] => Joop
            [id] => 65
            [chauffeurId] => 64
            [lat] => 52.9026474
            [lon] => 5.59003021194087
            [pickupdate] => 
            [departuretime] => 
            [arrivalTime] => 
            [finalDestination] => 
        )

)
```

What are possible ways to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way I can think of:

```
$result = [];

foreach ($array as $data) {
    $id = &$data['chauffeurId'];
    $data['timeDiff'] = abs($time - strtotime($data['arrivalTime']));
    $result[$id] = !isset($result[$id]) || $result[$id]['timeDiff'] > $data['timeDiff']
        ? $data
        : $result[$id];
}

print_r(array_values($result));
```

---

But if you want to use sorting:

Sort the array by the time difference, then iterate the array and store the time difference for each id.
Then you check if you have already iterated the current id, and the current time difference is bigger than the one you already iterated, then remove it.

```
$timeDiffs = [];

$time = strtotime("14:51:00");

usort($array, function ($item1, $item2) use ($time) {
    $diff1 = abs($time - strtotime($item1['arrivalTime']));
    $diff2 = abs($time - strtotime($item2['arrivalTime']));
    
    return $diff1 <=> $diff2;
});

foreach ($array as $key => $data) {
    $id = &$data['chauffeurId'];
    $timeDiff = abs($time - strtotime($data['arrivalTime']));
    
    
    if (isset($timeDiffs[$id]) && $timeDiff > $timeDiffs[$id]) {
        unset($array[$key]);
    } else {
        $timeDiffs[$id] = $timeDiff;
    }
}

print_r($array);
```